# Why do some websites offer fonts for free while some make you pay for the same ones?

Tags: android, css, fonts

I know this may seem stupid. But how come some websites seemingly provide fonts for free, while others make you pay for them. **Are the free ones somehow incomplete or of lower quality? - Are they missing more glyphs or something?** What am I missing?

Case in point.
http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Gotham-Rounded-Medium for free.
https://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham-rounded/styles/ for $200-.

I plan on using these fonts in android development specifically - but I guess the same question also applies in css during web development.

Comment: both sites offer that font for web use for free

Comment: @Tik observe that the second one has options to pay for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One offers the official license while the other just seems to offer the font. From looking at Fontsgeek, their terms and conditions mention that when you download the font, you take full responsibility for any copyright problems you may encounter.

They seemingly save themselves and only themselves by mentioning that "from their knowledge all fonts are available for free"

When it comes to Gotham, I'm about 90% sure you need a license in order to use it.

But take it with a grain of salt, I'm no lawyer. Just my observations from those two sites as well as experience with some font licensing in the past.

Comment: So the difference is legal and not technical?

Comment: @Alan - in the case you shared specifically, yes. To be honest though, I have noticed sometimes it is set up the free fonts are missing a glyph or maybe you're only getting one style. It's kinda a toss up when it comes to finding fonts online.